# Can RESTFUL API of Node js routed from a sub domain in godaddy which has its server hosted in aws

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I am working on a project where I have a node js applications with a restful api in aws ec2 instance, but when I try added a domain name to it because I want a domain for my api. I have tried it but the json response is enclosed inside a html tags

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>xyz.com</title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
        <frame src="http://zz.xx.yy.ww:9000/getdata" frameborder="0" />
        <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
    </frameset>
    <!-- pageok -->
    <!-- 09 -->
    <!-- -->

</html>
```

Is it possible to have a domain for api. Please need help, Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you set up a subdomain:

```
<frame src="http://zz.xx.yy.ww:9000/getdata" frameborder="0" />
```

Go Daddy does that when you "forward" a domain/subdomain using their service configuration... but this only works for HTML and even then it does not work well.

You need to create an actual DNS A record for the subdomain, pointing to the IP address where your service is hosted.